# Declaring array of struct in header without knowing size

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, global-variables

The problem I want to solve is the following: I take as input an integer, which will be the size of my array of structs. I want to define the array in a .h file, because both the size and the array must be global.

In the .h file I write extern NAME_OF_STRUCT my_array[];
Then in my .cpp file I write NAME_OF_STRUCT my_array[lenght_of_array]; to initialize it, but it throws this error:

"variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope"

What should I do? I do not know what to put inside it yet because I need to fill some values in the structs with data taken from text-input.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The compiler can't create your array if IT doesn't know how big it is at compile-time! If you haven't learned about dynamic memory allocation and pointers yet, it's time. And then, ultimately, hiding the pointers inside something like std::vector as an answer shows you --edit: actually does c++ allow variable length array declarations like in C now? The error message implies the problem is it being at file scope...

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<NAME_OF_STRUCT> my_array;
```

in cpp:

```
my_array.resize(length_ofarray);
```

Comment: Do I need to put #include <vector> in the .h file?

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I did what you suggested, but now I have these two errors: unknown type name 'node'node.resize(n_nodes);

error: cannot use dot operator on a type
node.resize(n_nodes);                                                                                    node is the name of the vector and n_nodes is its length.

Comment: Do you still have the problems? I was on vacation for a couple of days.